# How can I add shard at mongodb cluster?

Tags: mongodb, cluster-computing

I have setting-up mongodb 3.2 cluster as below configuration on my debian machines

```
# Config Server - mongod.conf

storage:
  dbPath: /data/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true

systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

net:
  port: 27019
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0

replication:
 replSetName: rs0

sharding:
 clusterRole: "configsvr"


# Shard Server 1 - mongod.conf

storage:
  dbPath: /data/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true

systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0

replication:
 replSetName: rs0


# Shard Server 2 - mongod.conf

storage:
  dbPath: /data/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true

systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0

replication:
 replSetName: rs0
```

and run mongos to add shard on query router server

$)mongos --configdb mongo-config:27019

but I can't add shard.

```
mongos> sh.addShard("rs0/mongo-db1:27017")
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Cannot add rs0/mongo-db1:27017 as a shard since it is part of a config server replica set",
    "code" : 96
}
mongos> sh.addShard("rs0/mongo-db1:27017")
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Surprised to discover that mongo-db1:27017 does not believe it is a config server",
    "code" : 72
}
```

getSharmap Command.

```
mongos> db.runCommand("getShardMap");
{
    "map" : {
        "config" : "rs0/mongo-db1:27017,mongo-db2:27017",
        "mongo-db1:27017" : "rs0/mongo-db1:27017,mongo-db2:27017",
        "mongo-db2:27017" : "rs0/mongo-db1:27017,mongo-db2:27017",
        "rs0/mongo-config:27019" : "rs0/mongo-config:27019",
        "rs0/mongo-db1:27017,mongo-db2:27017" : "rs0/mongo-db1:27017,mongo-db2:27017"
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

here is mongos log

2016-04-06T15:05:14.243+0000 I SHARDING [Balancer] about to log metadata event into actionlog: { _id: "mongo-router1-2016-04-06T15:05:14.243+0000-570525aa6b2b3378bb9daf56", server: "mongo-router1", clientAddr: "", time: new Date(1459955114243), what: "balancer.round", ns: "", details: { executionTimeMillis: 3, errorOccured: true, errmsg: "could not get updated shard list from config server due to Surprised to discover that mongo-db1:27017 does not believe it is a config server" } }

what I'm missing  .?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your shard you are trying to add is in rs0 replica set and since rs0 holds your config server it will not let you create the shard. Try adding it to a different replica set such as rs1 and that should work.